# Slax Linux installation: Error installing boot loader

Tags: system-installation

According to the Slax documentation, installation process is pretty easy. Copy the content, and run the installer file.

> ... navigate to /slax/boot/ directory on your USB device or hard disk
>   and locate bootinst.bat file there (Linux users look for bootinst.sh).
>   Just run it by double clicking, it will make all the necessary changes
>   to your device's master boot record so your computer's BIOS could
>   actually understand how to boot Slax from your disk. Keep in mind that
>   the boot installer does not support multiboot, so only Slax will be
>   bootable from the given drive.

https://www.slax.org/starting.php

However, I'm getting the following error during installation.

```
root@slax:/slax/boot# ls -l bootinst.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3333 Apr  5 05:34 bootinst.sh
root@slax:/slax/boot# 
root@slax:/slax/boot# ./bootinst.sh 
fdisk: cannot open aufs: No such file or directory
* attempting to install bootloader to /slax/boot...
./extlinux.x64: not a fat, ntfs, ext2/3/4, btrfs, xfs orufs1/2 filesystem: /slax/boot
Error installing boot loader.
Read the errors above and press enter to exit...

root@slax:/slax/boot#
```

If you need further info, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Experienced the same issue when I wrote the ISO to a USB stick. To resolve:

- Format USB stick as FAT32
- Manually copy `/slax` directory to USB
- Run `bootinst.sh`

Comment: I had tried, but still it can not be changed to executable.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you can execute the bootinst.sh from the terminal.

```
sudo bash /media/fergara/2G/slax/boot/bootinst.sh
```

Comment: This was help in that when I used the short-cut . and not the full path because I was in the directory where bootinst.sh existed, I got an error. Using the bash and full path worked. I didn't have time to test which of the two variables worked, but this answered pushed me in the right direction. Thank you.